# Can't read class objects from a file while using vector in c++

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2017

I'm learning C++ and I'm creating a simple C++ code in visual studio 2017 community. When the program read objects from a file then vs2017 gives an exception thrown.So how to solve this guys.

```
    fstream File; Company Temp;  try{ vector<Company>Object; // Company class name

        cout << " 1. Show Data "; 
        cout << " 2. Put Data\n";
        cout << " => ";
        int a; cin >> a; cin.ignore(1000, '\n');
        if (a == 1)
            throw 5;
        Temp.Get_Data();
        Object.push_back(Temp);
        File.open("Ma.bin", ios::binary | ios::out | ios::app);
        int i = 0;
        for (vector<Company>::iterator It = Object.begin(); It != Object.end(); It++) {
            File.write((char *)&Object[i], sizeof(Object[i]));
            i++;
        }
        File.close();

    }


    catch (int) {
        Object.clear();
        File.open("Ma.bin", ios::binary | ios::in);
        File.seekg(0, ios::end);
        auto total = File.tellg() / sizeof(Company);
        cout << " total Object write " << total << "\n";
        cout << " Which One you want to Dispaly ?"; int Number; cin >> Number; cin.ignore(1000, '\n');
        int Position = (Number - 1) * sizeof(Company);
        File.seekg(Position);
        File.read((char *)&Temp, sizeof(Temp)); //this is the bug , if i comment this line then programme runs ok
        Object.push_back(Temp);
        File.close();
        vector<Company>::iterator It = Object.begin();
        It->Put_Data();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

[image: this is the exception given by Vs2017 while reading objects from file]

Comment: You create `std::fstream File` in `try` block, but you use it in `catch` block. How does this compile?

Comment: @Yksisarvinen Maybe because there is another `File` variable in outer scope or because OP is not posting real code? But we can never be sure because this question lacks [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). I also suspect that `Company` is not a POD object so `File.write((char *)&Object[i], sizeof(Object[i]));` and `File.read((char *)&Temp, sizeof(Temp));` are wrong.

Comment: That's what I'm asking about, sorry if it sounded rude or something. I guess that `Object`, `File` and `Temp` might not be what OP expects them to be.

Comment: Is this a case of "I heard goto is bad so I'll use exceptions instead"? The problem with goto is not the word but the unstructured transfer of control.